# Managing consistent versions across multiple Maven projects

Tags: java, maven

I have a system consisting of various Java libraries and services, all built with Maven - each is a separate Maven projects which references a common parent pom project which defines a consistent set of versions of 3rd party libraries. Each of the projects uses properties to define the versions of dependencies within the stack.

At present, in order to build a set of release artefacts we have to work up the stack, doing a release build of each project. This entails manually changing the internal versions (in the properties section) to match the release stack versions.

For example, say we have 3 projects, A, B, & C, where C depends on A & B. Then the process would be:

1. Release build A.
2. Release build B.
3. Update C pom.xml to reference new release versions of A & B.
4. Commit pom.xml
5. Release build C.

With a large number of projects this becomes quite tedious and error-prone.

My question is, is there a preferred way to automate some of this, for example define release library versions in their own project? E.g. We centrally define the library versions that comprise Vx.y of the system. We then automate updating all of the project pom.xml files to use those versions.

One thing we have tried is putting the versions into the shared parent pom, however that creates a circular dependency, which leads to a never-ending cycle of changing the parent pom version, because a lib version had changed, which then entails updating all projects to pick up the new parent pom, which then requires a new parent pom and so on.

Comment: The first good thing is that you are using a common parent but the issue with this that you are using properties to define the versions of your dependencies. Better would be to define in the common parent only dependencyManagement and the version of the 3rd party libs. But you have to prevent using properties in your projects. Furthermore your release looks like you should use a multi module build which means simply put all your projects your a releasing together into a single multi module build and just release the whole in one.The only thing is that than all the module have the same version.

Comment: Such a multi module build can look like this: https://github.com/khmarbaise/javaee ...

Comment: We do use a dependencyManagement section in the parent Pim, however only for 3rd party libs. Putting stack versions in there seems circular as i point out above. I'm not completely convinced a multi-module approach will work, as we don't always release all components, and they all have different versions

Comment: The multi module setup will handle this which means a single release call (maven-release-plugin)..and that's it..Yes you will release modules which are not needed which does really hurt...furthermore you have a consistent state of all module which have the same version...You can use the different modules in one version of use older versions...The other solution will be to automate this release process by using Jenkins and a pipeline (versions-maven-plugin can help here)...but you will implement the order by yourself...if it is changed you need to change the job...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consensus answer seems to be - use a [Maven multi-module](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) project. I've tried this with two systems and found it actually works quite well.